# Would this question about practical jokes by the Star Trek crew be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question about practical jokes played by the members of the Star Trek TOS crew - namely, how many were there, and what were they.

My question is, is this question, which would involve things like William Shatner stealing Leonard Nimoy's bike (and towing his car), on topic?

It's about actors on a Star Trek show - but it doesn't really have anything to do with SF/F.

Comment: My initial instinct goes to "No", but I don't participate here often enough to know for sure...

Comment: Behind the scenes and out of universe stuff is definitely on-topic, though a list of all "practical jokes" sounds too broad or vague to make a good SE question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sure, go for it.

---

With my 'rules hat' on, I'll quote the help centre's [guide to what's on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine):

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - **Behind-the-scenes and fandom information**
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

A question about the behind-the-scenes antics of the Star Trek cast definitely qualifies under the "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" bullet-point.

---

Now with my 'reasonable hat' on, I'll say why I think this *should* be on-topic.

What we have here, on this site, is a community of **science fiction and fantasy experts**. A question like the one you suggest, while not being in-universe, is still going to be answerable by people who are Star Trek fanatics *(looking at you, @Praxis)* - it seems perfect for our site. (Admittedly the same argument could be applied to questions which are *not* on-topic, such as list and recommendation questions, but they fall under the "primarily opinion-based" bracket.) Provided your question isn't:

- too broad
- primarily opinion-based
- unclear what you're asking

(which it isn't), then hell, go for it!

---

**Bonus**: once you've asked your question, I'll upvote it :-)

Comment: There. I'll expect that 5 reputation shortly. :)

Comment: @Mithrandir Done.

Answer (score 3):

From the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine):

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - **Behind-the-scenes** and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

The subject itself it not off-topic. Some people may take umbrage at how "list-y" it is, or how broad it is, but that will depend on exactly what and how you ask.

Comment: Can you change your username to Jason Ninja Baker?

Comment: @randal'thor :o Then he'd be Jason, who bakes ninjas!